# Finding a general coefficient within a Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find a general expression $c_n$ in the Laurent series

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$$

for the function $f(z) = e^{z+1/z}$.

---

So I have

\begin{align}
f(z) &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-j}}{j!} \\
&= \sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \frac{z^{i-j}}{i!j!}
\end{align}

Now we want the coefficient $c_n$ so set $i-j=n$ then we have that

$$f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{z^n}{i!(i-n)!}$$

Now I'm not really sure how to simplify this. Can anyone provide some hints?

Comment: Mathematica tells us that the coefficient of $z^n$, namely $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!(k+|n|)!},$$ is $I_{|n|}(2)$, where $I_m(x)$ is the "modified Bessel function of the first kind".

Comment: Hi @GregMartin how would I find this though?

Comment: It would seem that you multiplied the sums term wise in your question. Have you considered finding a convolution of the two infinite sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the summation indices are non-negative, you have to split the summation on $n$
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0\, \le \,i \hfill \cr 
  0\, \le \,j \hfill \cr 
  i - j = n \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \to \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0\, \le \,j \hfill \cr 
  0\, \le \,n \hfill \cr 
  i = n + j \hfill \cr}  \right.\;\; \vee \;\left\{ \matrix{
  0\, \le \,i \hfill \cr 
  n < 0 \hfill \cr 
  j = i - n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Therefore:
$$
f(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i,\,j} {{{z^{\,i - j} } \over {i!j!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n\, < \,0} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i} {{1 \over {i!\left( {i - n} \right)!}}} } \right)z^{\,n} }  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {{1 \over {j!\left( {n + j} \right)!}}} } \right)z^{\,n} } 
$$
to get the result provided in the first comment

Comment: Hi, I'm not really familiar with your notation. Can you use similar notation I have used? In particular, what does $\vee$ mean?

Comment: $\vee$ stands for "union", "plus". The summation has to be conducted on the first quadrant of the $j,i$ plane. In this plane we introduce then the line $i=j+n$, and we have to switch the indices into $n$ and one of the parameters $i$ or $j$, keeping the other dependent. We do that by splitting the first quadrant into 1st and 2nd octant, which is the meaning of the  { $\to$ { $\vee$ { . And this is the splitting of the original sum in $i,j$ in the two sums in $i,n$ and $j,n$